# Find similar name in view based on other table

Tags: mysql, string, matching

I have one view from my database contains a lot of customer name and address

```
ID  Name    Address     Event
A1  Jon     California  Hockey
B3  Mark    Texas       Marathon
B4  marc    Texas       Marathon
A5  Jacobus Florida     Soccer
C2  BILLy    ALASKA      Basket
```

and then one  table master customer

```
Name
JOHN
MARK
JACOB
BILLY
```

I want to remove similar/duplicate name based on same address and event and repair misspell name automatically based on same characteristic then insert it into new table called true_customer so teh resut will be like this

```
ID  Name
A1  JOHN
B3  MARK
A5  JACOB
C2  BILLY
```

Note:
I can't use function like levenshtein etc this case

Comment: `Jon` is a common way to shorten the name `Jonathan`, and is totally different from `John`. The same is true of `Mark` and `Marc` (which is short for Marcus).  You need to figure out the exact logic you want to use, and figure out how you're going to differentiate actual names. You've proven so far that you've not yet done so.